# What is the name of this datetime format: "Sat Jul 28 00:00:00 MST 2012"

Tags: javascript, datetime

What is the name of this datetime format?

> Sat Jul 28 00:00:00 MST 2012

P.S.I'm using JavaScript.

Comment: I think thats the default date format mask in js

Comment: How did you output it ???? ie what function did you use ?

Comment: it's in the GeoJson output from Oracle database in another server..

Answer (score 0):

That is raw printing of JavaScript Date object, same as `date.toString();`

Comment: I have not said that this is format, this is raw printing of javascript object like you do this alert(new Date());

Comment: And I'm saying `alert(new Date())` will not produce a date string in that format. http://jsfiddle.net/wQHaN/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the RFC1123 date format.

http://www.hackcraft.net/web/datetime/#rfc822

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#RFC1123

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822

Comment: Hmmmm looks like I got confused about the placement of the `year`.